# Deploy an Uipath in an Azure virtual machine

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, uipath, uipath-orchestrator, uipath-robot

I have created a VM with the free trial account of Azure with a basic components and a Windows 10. I have installed last version of UiPath and it is working fine, but when I close the RDP connetion (clicking in the "X"), the running execution failed.
I think it is because the selectors does not work when the "screen" is displayed. But I don't know how to keep the VM as if it was displayed to avoid the fail of the execution when I close it.
Any advice?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to either:

- Run your process on an unattended robot

or

- Run attended and keep the RDP open

Comment: I launched the process through orchestrator as an unattended robot and it works, but the RDP connection dies just after the execution start. Why does that happen? Is there a way to avoid it?
And when I log back in, it is still running correctly

Comment: The Robot Agent "takes over" your RDP connection which is why you will see it disconnects you, and is unavoidable afaik. When you reestablish the connection you take it back from the Robot Agent. 

I think UIPath designed it this way because the agent also works with Windows Server where it can run in multiple instances simultaneously, but I'm not too sure on this point.

For a production process do you really want to watch it work live? Because then an attended setup would suit you better (even though it is against the principles).

Answer (score 0):

As Mads T said above you have 2 options when running process on a Virtual Machine.

**Attended**

You need to remain logged into RDP for this to work

**Unattended**

Do you have an instance of Orchestrator, you can use the free community version UiPath offer at https://cloud.uipath.com/

From Orchestrator you can start your process on the Virtual Machine without having it open.connected to via RDP

UiPath has more documentation on this subject here https://docs.uipath.com/orchestrator/docs/attended-vs-unattended-automation